# Assigning value from a 2d array to a class

Tags: c++

I'm working on a textual game, I wish to assign a weapon to a player or monster.
I have created a 2d array with min & max damage so I can randomize every hits between min/max.

But I'm stuck for now.
Should I integrate the 2d array in the weapon class ?
How to affect the weapon to each player ?

thanks for any help :)

```
#include <iostream>

class player{
public:
    std::string playerName;
    int health; 
    int maxmana;
    int minDegatWeapon;
    int maxDegatWeapon;
};

class weapon{
public:
    std::string weaponName;
    int maxDegatWeapon;
    int minDegatWeapon;
};

void createPlayer(player *p, weapon *w){
    int weaponSelection = 0;
    std::cout << "Player Name ?\n";
    std::getline (std::cin,p->playerName);
    p->health = 20;
    p->maxmana = 80;
    std::cout << "Choose your Weapon : 1-Dagger / 2-Sword / 3-Axe ? \n";
    std::cin >> weaponSelection;
};

int main(){

    player human = {" ", 0, 0, 0, 0};
    weapon humanWeapon = {" ", 0, 0};

int weapons[3][2] = {
    {3,4}, //dagger
    {1,6}, //sword
    {0,7} //axe
};

    createPlayer(&human, &humanWeapon);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not assignable, they are copyable... You can assign to a pointer -- but that points back to the original array and is only valid during the original's lifetime..

Answer (score 1):

You can always have `class Weapon` be an abstract class. There is no "generic weapon" so it would not be appropriate to instantiate an object of type weapon. Instead, have multiple classes inherit from the weapon class, and adjust their min/max value as needed. Further more, you can assign this weapon to the player by adding a weapon to the Player class.

```
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
class Weapon
{
public:
  virtual std::string getWeaponType() = 0;
  virtual int generateDamage() = 0;
  int minDmg, maxDmg;
};

class Sword : public Weapon
{
public:
  Sword()
  {
    minDmg = 1;
    maxDmg = 6;
  }
  std::string getWeaponType()
  {
    return "SWORD";
  }
  int generateDamage()
  {
    return ( rand() % maxDmg + minDmg );
  }
};

class Player
{
public:
  Player(int weapon)
  {
    if(weapon == 1)
    {
       w = new Sword();
    }
    //else if(weapon == 2).....
    //..................
  }
  Weapon* getWeapon()
  {
    return w;
  }
private:
  Weapon* w;
};

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL)); //random seed
  Player p1 = Player(1);
  std::cout << p1.getWeapon().generateDamage() << '\n'; //see if it works
}
```

Comment: for your weapon pointer I would also reccomment using ```std::unique_ptr<Weapon> w ``` so it properly gets deleted, otherwise implement a correct destructor once the game ends

Comment: Just modified this sentence : ``` std::cout << p1.getWeapon()->generateDamage() << '\n'; //see if it works``` <br> some part of your code is still a bit to complex for current level :)

Comment: @CTRL-Z the arrow is actually necessary for the code to work, it only indicates that the function is being called from a pointer. ```getWeapon() ``` returns a weapon pointer, so to use any of the functions in the weapon class (or sword or whatever is inheriting from it) you need to use ```->```

Comment: you can just make the weapon a non-pointer if it is easier!